# Quantifying arthmetical skill

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic

Question for a research project:

What is the standard way of quantifying a student's skill in arithmetic ranging from having to look up numbers on a times-table to computing large sums in their head in a few seconds?

Comment: What makes you think that there is a standard way, especially if you don't give details like age of the student (third grade or college?), location, etc?

Comment: I thought 'what is your preferred way' would be too opinion based a question. I didn't give details about the student because this is implied by saying the student is within the wide range described as 'from having to look up numbers on a times-table to computing large sums in their head in a few seconds'.

Comment: +1. I think the question would be improved if you asked "Is there a standard or commonly accepted way, and if not, do you have a reference to someone who successfully quantified it" rather than "what is the standard way," but otherwise I can imagine decent answers here from someone who has knowledge of a research paper that already had to deal with this question.

Comment: There's the ACCUPLACER Arithmetic test, mostly intended for remedial college placement: https://accuplacer.collegeboard.org/student/inside-the-test

Comment: I could let the student answer as many questions as they can in 15 minutes where they choose the difficulty of the questions and harder questions earn more points, but then I would have to justify this method in my thesis.

Comment: @BostonBrooks The method you suggested would not (only) test the students arithmetic skills but rather their time management. The reason for such tests (as far as I know them) is to teach the student to drop questions after an appropriate time if he got stuck. This is a skill that really needs to be learned by college freshmen, as they are often used to a linear "solve everything in order" approach...

Comment: @DanielR.Collins That comment looks like it could be an answer with a little more detail.

Comment: Perhaps you should consult the responses to [Mathematics Self-Efficacy Questionnaire](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/12629/511).